# What is the equation family of the projectile-motion-with-air-resistance eqn?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

The general form of the equations of projectile motion with air resistance are (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance))

$s_y(t) = -\frac{mg}{k}t + \frac{m}{k}\left(v_{yo} + \frac{mg}{k}\right)\left(1 - e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\right)$

and

$s_x(t) = \frac{m}{k}v_{xo}\left(1-e^{-\frac{k}{m}t}\right)$

The question I have is: to which general family of equations do these solution to ODE belong? I need to fit this equation to data, and would like to use the generic form.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

@Tony Piccolo suggested [this presentation](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/sp14/JoeHays/presentation.pdf) that offers the following derivation (thanks!):

$y=\left( \frac{mg \sec\theta}{bV_0}+\tan \theta \right)x+\frac{m^2g}{b^2}\ln \left(1-\frac{b \sec\theta}{mV_0}x\right)$

which was actually what I was looking for. Thanks Tony!

Comment: Why did you use the tags _conic-sections_ and _hyperbolic-functions_ ?

Comment: updated. thanks. Any ideas on an answer?

Comment: The trajectory is not a standard curve and has not a special name. It has a vertical asymptote (terminal velocity): however, for $k \to 0$, it becomes a parabola.

Comment: I'm interested in describing the assymetry of the trajectory, so in my case $k \neq 0$

Comment: [This](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math55/deproj/sp14/JoeHays/presentation.pdf) can be useful.

Comment: It actually is very useful since it expresses $y=f(x)$! Thanks Tony!